# Custom font for semantic fonts styles such as headline, body, etc?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to use the semantic font styles, but also want to use a custom font. Is this possible so I can continue using `.font(.headline)` in the code but using my own custom font?

Answer (score 1):

1. add your custom fonts to your project:

[image: add your custom fonts to your project:]

2. add your custom fonts to your project's info.plist:

[image: Add your custom fonts to the info.plist:]

3. Add extension:

```
extension NSAttributedString.Key {
    public enum SourceSansPro: String {
        case black = "SourceSansPro-Black"
        case blackItalic = "SourceSansPro-BlackIt"
        case bold = "SourceSansPro-Bold"
        case boldItalic = "SourceSansPro-BoldIt"
        case extraLight = "SourceSansPro-ExtraLight"
        case extraLightItalic = "SourceSansPro-ExtraLightIt"
        case italic = "SourceSansPro-It"
        case light = "SourceSansPro-Light"
        case lightItalic = "SourceSansPro-LightIt"
        case regular = "SourceSansPro-Regular"
        case semibold = "SourceSansPro-Semibold"
        case semiboldItalic = "SourceSansPro-SemiboldIt"
    }
}
```

4. Add extension:

```
extension Font {
    static func my(font: NSAttributedString.Key.SourceSansPro, size: CGFloat) -> Font {
        return self.custom(font.rawValue, size: size)
    }
}
```

5. Use:

```
Text("Title")
    .font(.my(font: .bold, size: 17))
```